# links on yahoo mail not working

Tags: html, email, yahoo, spam

i am facing a strange problem on yahoo email , once email arrive at spam folder all my links would be not clickable , inspecting the element found that the entire href attribute has been removed ! after some researches on the net found that that is related to the structure of the link , folks saying that link must begin with `http://` and i did it but still links are not clickable on spam folder , any suggestions ?
this is a part of my email body code :

```
<tr><td width="600" align="center" valign="middle">
                    <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="noindex ,nofollow" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" >visit the site </a> </td> </tr>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Yahoo removes the links in mail that's marked as spam so that you don't accidentally click on them. Do the links start working if you mark the mail as not spam?

Comment: yes links work if i mark them as not spam , this issue is happening only with yahoo others isp hotmail, gmail there is no problem at all , same links work normal

Comment: Then I don't see what the problem is. The spam folder is specifically meant for messages that you *don't* want. If your mail is actually wanted the recipient will move it out of the spam folder.

Comment: It might make more sense to check in detail _why_ your messages are marked as spam. There must be a reason for that. And usually that is a good one.

Comment: this is a simple and  a technique question , i mean is there a way for links on yahoo spam folder to stay working ?  like hotmail , gmail ... are doing so achieve inbox folder ... this is another question

Comment: No, there isn't. If there was the entire feature would be completely useless.